# How to assign select option values to picklist field

Tags: salesforce-id

I want to assign selectOption values to picklist field.
like:

```
public String[] selectOptions{get;set;}
Object obj = new Object(picklistfield = selectOptions);
```

can I do like this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign the LOVs for a pick list field like this. You have add the values in LOV through configuration . However, you can instantiate an object like this , assign the selected value and created a record that goona have a selected values.

Comment: Basically i am querying on a object, from where i am getting some values then assigning them to picklist field to display in vf page